# What's the recommended way to download/upload video in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native, webapi

We are using ionic v4 with angular, and we want to download/upload some videos.
What's the recommended way to achieve it?

I know we can use cordova fileTransfer, but it is **deprecated**.

I found another article about using web API `requestFileSystem`, but it seems this is no standard API, and i do not get code suggestion in TS code.

I also found example by using ionic natvie HTTP, it is still based on cordova plugin.

Does anyone has some experience on this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Capacitor HTTP plugin](https://github.com/capacitor-community/http), which has support for file upload/download. It's built for Capacitor, Ionic's official native runtime. It looks like you're using Cordova - note that Capacitor 99% backward compatible though so you could integrate it then try the HTTP plugin.